# InvalidArgumentException View [back.admin] not found

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have checked the path, and I checked the route. Unfortunately, nothing helps. I'm getting an error here:

**DashboardController.php**

```php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function admin()
    {
        return view('back.admin');
    }
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'admin'])
    ->name('back.admin');
```

> InvalidArgumentException
> View [back.admin] not found.
> http://localhost:8000/admin

Comment: Have you tried using another view to see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return view ('back.admin') in the admin function in the controller
There is no file named views / back / admin under the resources folder. Can you check the file path?

Answer (score 1):

We should put the `view` file in the following directory to make it work:

```
resources/views/back/admin.blade.php
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer. Because it's correct. The question we both ask is what 'back' actually means. In a real world scenario, it should be `admin.index` and the blade file at `resources/views/admin/index.blade.php`. I only wanted to give this piece of information to @Emtn as a guideline.